# Iterating over a .json file and changing a attribute value

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to iterate over a .json file with a small script to find a attribute named 'model' and change it's value on each object. (It's a db-dump from Django).

```
import codecs, json

data = ""

with codecs.open("dump2.json", 'r', 'utf8') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

for i in data:
    for key in i:
        if key[0] == 'model':
            key[1] = "app.model" #not working

with codecs.open('dump2.json', 'w', 'utf8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I don't get any errors. And values are not changed.

Comment: Can you please show us an example of your json?

Comment: Anand, I dont think it's anything wrong with the json. It's a file generated from djangos 'dumpdata' command and it works when printing key[1] just not when assigning the new value.

Comment: Well unless you provide an example of your json, that works with your code , we would have no idea what `data` or `i` or `key` or anything else for that matter is? How do you think we would be able to advice what is going wrong?

Comment: @user3199840, Even if there is no problem with the json itself, it is much easier to help knowing what is making yout trouble. Otherwise advises would be based only on guesses

Comment: Ok. I'll be back with further documentation on whats going on here.

Comment: @user3199840, I'm assuming you have a manage.py dumpdata output. If so, you want to change the value for the model key? Or for the next (subsequent) key?

Comment: Yes André, i have a dumpdata database output that i need to import to another project. But i need to change the 'model attribute from "oldapp.modelname" to "newapp.modelname" before i can loaddata in the new project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on some random documentation I found on the [web](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata). I assume you have such a json structure:

```
[
    {

        "pk": 1,
        "model": "auth.user",
        "fields":{
            "username": "test1"
        }
    },{
        "pk": 2,
        "model": "auth.user",
        "fields":{
            "username": "test2"
        }
    }
]
```

Using this json as example, when your code executes it iterates correctly over json keys on the line `for i in data:`. But on the second loop `for key in i:`, you are iterating over a string ("model" string). So, in this case, `key[0]` is `'m'`, `key[1]` is `'o'` and so on...

You should try this way:

```
import codecs, json

data = ""

with codecs.open("dump2.json", 'r', 'utf8') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

for i in data:
    for key in i:
        if key=="model":
            i[key] = "app.model"

with codecs.open('dump2.json', 'w', 'utf8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```